# Prove or disprove that $(0,1)$ complete.

Tags: metric-spaces

A metric is defined on $X=(0,1)$ by 
$d(x,y)=\left|\frac 1x -\frac 1y\right|$.

> Is this space complete or not?

*My attempt:* I have shown that there does not exist any $x_n$ that tends to 0 ($x_n\neq 0$ for all $n$). Because if $x_n$ tends to 0 then $1/x_n$ tends to infinity. Therefore $d(x_n,x_m)=\vert 1/x_n - 1/x_m\vert$ is not less than epsilon. Because keeping $m$ fixed and tending $n$ to infinity we can get $d(x_n,x_m)$ greater than epsilon.

Finally I have to show if $x_n$ tends to $x\neq 0$ then x is in $(0,1)$.
$d(1/x_n, 1/x) < \epsilon$ implies $|x-x_n| <x \epsilon$. I can't proceed any further.

Comment: There's a Cauchy sequence converging to $1\notin X$.

Comment: Hint: $(0,1)$ is isometric to $(1,\infty)$ through the map $x \mapsto \frac1x$. Is $(1,\infty)$ with euclidean metric complete?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The question was not properly edited by Latex. That's why i am unchanging my question.

Comment: I'm a little lost.  It seems like something is missing.  I don't understand the metric.

Comment: Do you want $d(x,y)=1/x-1/y$?  But then you need absolute values or something.

Comment: No, i want absolutely value of (1/x -1/y). That means modulus sign of (1/x -1/y).

Comment: Ok.  Now I get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106034/discussion-between-algebra-algebra-and-chris-custer).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $x_n=1/n$.  Then $x_n\in(0,1)$ and $x_n$ is Cauchy, since $d(x_n,x_m)=|1/n-1/m|\le1/n+1/m \le2/N$, for $n,m\ge N\gt0$.

$x_n$ doesn't converge in $X$.  Take a prospective limit, say $l\in(0,1)$.  Then let $N$ be large enough so that $x_N\lt l/2$.  Then $d(x_n,l)\ge l/2$, for all $n\ge N$.

Hence $(X,d)$ is not complete.

Comment: You should show (or at least mention!) that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in the given metric. The fact that $x_n\to 1$ in the Euclidean metric is irrelevant here.

Comment: @TonyK  my mistake.  I should have read more carefully.

Comment: But $d(x_n,1)$ is not defined, because $1\notin X$. You have to look at $d(x_n,x_m)$.

Comment: @TonyK  thanks.  I really bogeyed this one.